# Авторизация через WebMoney

Tags: webmoney, php

Решил сделать авторизацию через WebMoney, на WebMoney.com сделал все правильно, по инструкции, осталось только скрипт, нашел в интернете исходный скрипт, но он выдает "**=== Ошибка при получении тикета ===**".

test.php

```
<a href='https://login.wmtransfer.com/GateKeeper.aspx?RID=FCF5C9F9-82FE-4FBB-B689-A41D013F4A84'>Авторизация через WM</a>
```

wmlogin.php (обработчик)

```
<?php 
$urlid = "FCF5C9F9-82FE-4FBB-B689-A41D013F4A84";

if($_POST[WmLogin_UrlID] == $urlid) { 
    echo "=== Тикет получен успешно === <br>";
    // Продолжаем выполнение скрипта
    // ...
} else {
    echo "=== Ошибка при получении тикета ===";
}
?>
```

urlid правильный, копировал с сайта https://login.wmtransfer.com/RealmUrls.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выведите `$urlid` и `$_POST[WmLogin_UrlID]` на экран - и вы все поймете! Вчера сам 2 часа вникал, где у меня ошибка! Дело в том, что `$_POST[WmLogin_UrlID]` сервер возвращает маленькими буквами!

Сейчас у самого проблема здесь:

Делаю, как в инструкции:

```
$xml="
        <request>
         <siteHolder>$mywmid</siteHolder>
         <user>".$_POST['WmLogin_WMID']."</user>
         <ticket>".$_POST['WmLogin_Ticket']."</ticket>
         <urlId>".$urlid."</urlId>
         <authType>".$_POST['WmLogin_AuthType']."</authType>
         <userAddress>".$_POST['WmLogin_UserAddress']."</userAddress>
        </request>
        ";
```

Затык происходит, видимо, на:

```
<authType>".$_POST['WmLogin_AuthType']."</authType>
```

потому что при запросе:

```
print "WmLogin_WMID:&nbsp;".$_POST['WmLogin_WMID']."<br>";
print "WmLogin_Ticket:&nbsp;".$_POST['WmLogin_Ticket']."<br>";
print "WmLogin_AuthType:&nbsp;".$_POST['WmLogin_AuthType']."<br>";
print "WmLogin_UserAddress:&nbsp;".$_POST['WmLogin_UserAddress']."<br>";
```

Получаем все, кроме `AuthType`:

```
WmLogin_WMID: 34........56
WmLogin_Ticket: ckD............(скрыл на всякий случай)...........sk6Qob8
WmLogin_AuthType: 
WmLogin_UserAddress: 178.90.106.76
```